# Xamarin iOS: The post for client build... has been cancelled

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I am unable to launch my Xamarin App from visual studio on my PC to the iOS Simulator on a networked Mac.

I am getting the following error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): warning : The post for client build7148techn on topic xvs/Build/4.2.0.680/execute-task/RFTIOS/5434a49%2FDetectSdkLocations has been cancelled
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): warning : The operation was canceled.
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): warning :    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): warning :    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): warning :    at Xamarin.Messaging.Client.MessagingClient.d__23`2.MoveNext() in C:\data\lanes\3513\c4382f51\source\xamarinvs\src\Messaging\Xamarin.Messaging.Client\MessagingClient.cs:line 135
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(543,3): error : The post for client build7148techn on topic xvs/Build/4.2.0.680/execute-task/RFTIOS/5434a49%2FDetectSdkLocations has been cancelled

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To get a good answer, you should ask a good question. Look at the help article, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, on how to do that.

Comment: I don't see any problem with this question. It precisely explains the problem (in the first sentence) and includes the error message.

Answer (score 23):

@boulev and tie: I had the same issue today and I can confirm that you only have to restart Visual Studio. That's enough.

Comment: Tried everything. Even disconnected the Mac and reconnected. Restart Visual Studio and bam! it works. Guess it's just like Windows. Always have to restart

Answer (score 14):

Your "question" is not very descriptive but nevertheless Google got me here. I just got a similar error today. This is what worked for me (not sure if all steps are necessary to fix the issue)

1. Restart MAC
2. Restart PC
3. Remove bin and obj folder under the project folder
4. Clean the project (in Visual Studio)
5. Rebuild

Comment: Same here. Cleaning project did not work. Closing visual studio and reopening did the trick. Did not need to restart pc/mac or manually clean bin/obj

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error and it turns out that on the mac I was paired to was asking if i would like to allow something. I simply had to say yes and type in my mac password.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem when my app has too many bundled resources.  Unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet; I've asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70920352/xamarin-forms-ios-app-cant-be-deployed-with-too-many-bundleresource-files).